# How to insert data into 4 tables that have relationships using LINQ to sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have 4 tables in SQL server. These tables have relationships with foreign keys. i get 20 fields from user in asp.net MVC website and want to insert these 20 fields(Name,Family,Address,Account Number,...) to these tables. For this operation i use LINQ to SQL in c#. I want the operation of inserting to be in a transaction scope.

**person** table:
[Row Id],[Name],[family],[Father Name],[Sex],[Birth Date],[Nationality Code],[Issue Number],[Marital Status],[live]

**Address** table: 
[Row Id],[Person_Row Id],[State City_Row Id],[Address],[Tel],[Mobile]

**Account** Table: 
[Row Id],[Account Number],[Card Number]

**Patient File** Table:
[Row Id],[File Code],[Person_Row Id],[Doctor_Row Id],[Charity_Row Id]
 ,[Illness_Row Id],[Account_Row Id]

Comment: Lookup "transactions". They are what you want, the essence "all or nothing" (in terms of statements to run)

Comment: Do you have a code sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can do what you want :

```
 using(YourDbContext dc = new YourDbContext())
 {
   person prs = new person();
   prs.Name = "person1";
   prs.FatherName = "Father1";
   ...



   prs.Addresses.Add(
     new Address()
     {
        Address = "Address1 No1",
        Tel = "000000",
        ...
     });

   prs.Accounts.Add(
     new Account()
     {
        AccountNumber = "123456",
        CardNumber = "000000"
        ....
     }); 


   dc.Persons.Add(prs);
   dc.SaveChanges();
 }
```

Comment: how will I pass the foreign Keys to the relationship tables?